# How to relay the terminate signal onto Spring Boot if handling the signal in code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a function that catches the terminate signal and does some finishing touches to the application (logging, closing some of the internal app components, etc.) After doing so, I want to relay this terminate signal onto Spring Boot so it gracefully terminates/shuts down. Right now it just hangs for 3 minutes before dying.

```
{
...
final Signal signal = new Signal("TERM");
Signal.handle(signal, Signal -> { terminate(signal); });
}

private static void terminate(Signal signal) {
     EZLog.getGlobalInstance().info("Signal received: " + signal.getName());
     app.shutdown();
     updateECSTaskStatusToStopped();
     // relay shutdown onto spring boot
}
```

How would I approach that correctly?

Comment: Spring boot already gracefully shutsdown. So instead of doing this, do it the other way around, let Spring Boot manage this and trigger your stops.

Comment: @M.Deinum how would I then do all the finishing tasks if Spring Boot manages the termination?

Comment: Spring has callbacks which are triggered when an application shutsdown. Use those instead of this. That way it is part of the termination of the Spring Boot application.